# Zero point of derivative of differentiable increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

If $f:\,\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a differentiable function, $f'(x)\ge 0,\;\forall\,x\in\mathbb R$ and $\left\{x\in\mathbb R:\;f'(x)=0\right\}\subset \mathbb Q$ then $f(x)$ is an increasing function.

Now, I want to ask a question

Is there a differentiable function $f:\,\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $f'(x)>0,\;\forall\,x\in\mathbb Q$ and $f'(x)=0,\;\forall\,x\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$?

Comment: How are your "two questions" different from each other?

Answer (score 5):

This is answer for both of your questions.

$f'$ has IVP. Since $f'(x) >0$ for $x $ rational and $f'(x) =0$ for $x $ irrational it follows that $f'$ takes uncountably many values. But $f'=0$ for $x $ irrational  and $f'(\mathbb Q)$ is a countable set. This is a contradiction, so such a function does not exist.

For IVP (Intermediate Value Property) see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand "IVP"

Comment: @Drona I have added a reference.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I have one more question. Is there a differentiable function $f:\,\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $f'(x)\ge 0,\;\forall\,x\in\mathbb R$ and $$\left\{x\in\mathbb R:\;f'(x)=0\right\}=\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q ?$$

Comment: That is the question I have answered.